# Using Javascript to detect the bottom of the window and ignoring all events when a request is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anonymous function to detect the user has scrolled to the bottom of the window. Inside of the anonymous function, I have a call to a database that takes a while to complete.

```
var allowing_more = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (allowing_more == 1){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            allowing_more = 0;
            //query
            allowing_more = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

In this time, if the user scrolls to the bottom of the window again, it seems a queue is made holding the occurences the user scrolled to the bottom of the window while the query was loading. Upon completing of the query, these occurences are then executed.

I have a boolean statement to detect if the anonymous function is accepting more query requests but this seems to be ignored.

Is there some sort of way to ignore an anonymous function temporarily and re-enable it?

Comment: All you need is you have to stop querying your database until the previous request completes is this correct?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom while the previous request is still executing, it will execute again. If I hold the page down key for a second, it seems to queue 6 or 7 of these events.

Comment: It would be nice if you also added pseudo code for how you're handling the boolean toggle you described. It might be as simple as adjusting the placement of where the boolean is toggled... But from the current code example it's impossible to tell... One thing comes to mind is that you're resetting the boolean within the `if` block and not when the `callback` function is executed...

Answer (score 0):

All you need is you have to stop querying your database until the previous request completes is this correct?

if this is correct

```
var chkFlg=0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        if(chkFlg===1){
           //query your database after you get your result from db assign 1 to chkFlg
            chkFlg = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is currently what I have. I have a boolean value that is set to be false inside of the statement and true outside of the statement but nothing changes compared to what I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if(flag===0){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        //query
      flag = 1;
    }
   flag = 0;
  }
});
```

This should work

Comment: This is currently what I have. A boolean statement to check if the page is allowing more scroll downs. However, these events seem to be queued rather than checked as they come along. Nothing changes apart from what I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this kind of pattern and your boolean condition should work.

```
safeToQuery = true;  //
$(window).scroll(function() {
    ...
    if (safeToQuery) {
        safeToQuery = false;
        //send query request
        $.ajax({...}).done(function(data,etc){
            //do whatever with the results
        }).always(function (){
            //regardless of whether or not the last request resulted 
            //in an error, make it safe to query again
            safeToQuery = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Note: `safeToQuery` doesn't have to be a global, you could declare it as a local variable in an  [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or just make it a property of some object that lives at least as long as you need to keep the scroll handler active.